# Create dataframe from list of dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a list `myList` that contains 16 `data.frames`

```
List of 16

    $ dataframe1           :'data.frame':   20 obs. of  60 variables:
      ..$ Stat            : Factor w/ 16 levels "a","b",..: 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
      ..$ P10             : num [1:31] 1 3 2 2 4 8 0 4 2 5 ...
      ..$ R               : num [1:31] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
      ..$ S               : num [1:31] 0 7 7 1 5 9 3 9 6 2 ...

    $ dataframe2           :'data.frame':   20 obs. of  60 variables:
      ..$ Stat            : Factor w/ 16 levels "c","d",..: 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
      ..$ P10             : num [1:31] 2 1 2 2 5 6 7 2 2 5 ...
      ..$ R               : num [1:31] NA 1 NA NA 2 NA 4 NA NA NA ...
      ..$ S               : num [1:31] 10 2 4 1 5 8 8 8 1 2 ...
...
..
```

I need the `mean` from each column and get the results in a `data.frame`.

```
       dataframe1     dataframe2     ....
 Stat  NA             NA
 P10   6              7
 R     NA             3
 S     12             14
 ...   ...            ...             ...
```

I have this `lapply(myList$variable1, mean)` which returns me the results for one `data.frame` in that list. 
`ldply(myList, data.frame)` does not include the `mean` function. 
How would I do that for the whole list and bring it into one `data.frame`?

Comment: Try `sapply(myList, colMeans, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: How is your list structured? In the output you paste above it looks highly nested---it looks like the first item in the list is a data frame named `Variable1` and that data frame has a column of data frames also called `Variable1`...

Comment: @akrun I get `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'x' must be numeric`

Comment: @Stophface Perhaps you have a nested list as Gregor mentioned. How about `lapply(myList, sapply, colMeans, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun nope. Its a list containing 30 `data.frames`. Each dataframe has 20 columns. The columns are mixed. `Factor`, `numeric`, `character` etc.

Comment: Why is it so hard to add a reproducible example?

Comment: In that case, `sapply(myList, function(x)  sapply(x, function(y) if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE) else NA))`

Comment: @akrun thats it. The last `function(y)` needs to be run with `function(x)` though.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo

Comment: @akrun I did not know that you can nest the `sapply` function. Makes perfectly sense now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a nested `sapply`.  The first one will loop through the `list` and second will loop through the columns of the `data.frame`, based on the condition whether the column is `numeric`, we get the `mean` or else return NA.

```
sapply(myList, function(x) sapply(x, function(y)
              if(is.numeric(y)) mean(y, na.rm=TRUE) else NA))
```